# Algoritmo em JavaScript para fazer uma contagem regressiva de um horário especifico

Tags: javascript

Estou com código que me mostra a hora atual funcionando corretamente e dois input's para digitar a hora e o minuto em que eu desejo que o tempo restante até a hora e o minuto determinado seja calculado, a hora eu consigo calcular corretamente porém os minutos dependendo do horário ele me retorna um valor negativo

```
if (horaAtual <= nAcordarHora) {
                var auxHora = horaAtual - nAcordarHora
                //auxHora serve para transformar p número negativo para um número positivo
                //Multiplique qualquer número por -1 que o número se tornará positivo
                var resultHora = auxHora * -1
                //Calculando minuto
                if (minutoAtual <= nAcordarMinuto) {
                    var auxMinuto = minutoAtual - nAcordarMinuto
                    var resultMinuto = auxMinuto * -1
                    tempoRestante.innerHTML = `Você tem apenas ${resultHora}h:${resultMinuto}m`
                } else {
                    var auxMinuto = 60 - minutoAtual
                    var resultMinuto = auxMinuto - nAcordarMinuto
                    var resultHora = resultHora - 1
                    tempoRestante.innerHTML = `Você tem apenas ${resultHora}h:${resultMinuto}m primeiro if`
                }
                //Calculando hora
            } else {
                var auxHora = 24 - horaAtual
                var resultHora = auxHora + nAcordarHora
                //Calculando minuto
                if (minutoAtual <= nAcordarMinuto) {
                    var auxMinuto = minutoAtual - nAcordarMinuto
                    var resultMinuto = auxMinuto * -1
                    tempoRestante.innerHTML = `Você tem apenas ${resultHora}h:${resultMinuto}m`
                } else {
                    var auxMinuto = 60 - minutoAtual
                    var resultMinuto = auxMinuto - nAcordarMinuto
                    var resultHora = resultHora - 1
                    tempoRestante.innerHTML = `Você tem apenas ${resultHora}h:${resultMinuto}m dsdadada`
                }
            }
```

Comment: Quando `nAcordarMinuto` eh menor que `minutoAtual`, vc tem que somar os minutos, e nao subtrair. Por exemplo, a diferenca entre 6h50 e 7h30 eh 40 minutos. Ou seja, `60-50 + 30` e nao `60-50 - 30`, como voce esta fazendo.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi, vou tentar aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro transformar tudo em segundos e em seguida manipular o resultado por divisão de tempo. Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```js
const horaAtual = new Date();
var nAcordarHora = new Date();
nAcordarHora.setDate(nAcordarHora.getDate() + 1); //adicionei 1 dia aqui
nAcordarHora.setHours(nAcordarHora.getHours() + 3); //adicionei 3h
nAcordarHora.setMinutes(nAcordarHora.getMinutes() + 30); //adicionei 30m
nAcordarHora.setSeconds(nAcordarHora.getSeconds() + 15); //adicionei 15s

const C_MINUTO = 60;
const C_HORA = C_MINUTO * 60;

const horaAtualValor = horaAtual.setMilliseconds(0); //convertendo em números (formato unix)
const nAcordarHoraValor = nAcordarHora.setMilliseconds(0); //convertendo em números (formato unix)
const intervaloEmSegundos = Math.floor((nAcordarHoraValor - horaAtualValor) / 1000);
const horasFaltando = Math.floor(intervaloEmSegundos / C_HORA);
const minutosFaltando = Math.floor((intervaloEmSegundos - (horasFaltando * C_HORA)) / C_MINUTO);
const segundosFaltando = (intervaloEmSegundos - (horasFaltando * C_HORA) - (minutosFaltando * C_MINUTO));

console.log('horaAtual: '+ horaAtual);
console.log('nAcordarHora: '+ nAcordarHora);
console.log('horaAtualValor: '+ horaAtualValor);
console.log('nAcordarHoraValor: '+ nAcordarHoraValor);
console.log('intervaloEmSegundos: '+ intervaloEmSegundos);
console.log('horasFaltando: ' + horasFaltando);
console.log('minutosFaltando: ' + minutosFaltando);
console.log('segundosFaltando: ' + segundosFaltando);
```